# Where do I find the "endpoint" parameter to integrate AWS Secrets?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am pretty new at the AWS SDK world, and my first project is to collect information from secrets using a Spring Application.

I have been using this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/manage-credentials-using-aws-secrets-manager.html all good with the code but something I cannot wrap my head around is the "endpoint", where do I find this information inside AWS web console? Is it something that companies can personalize?

This would be the first cooperative project... Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [the list of public endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/asm.html) for AWS Secrets Manager. You would pick the one for the AWS region you are using. If you aren't using a VPC endpoint then you can probably just leave that blank or `null`, the AWS SDK should pick the endpoint automatically based on the region.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Secret Manager with a Spring project, use the Secret Manager Java API V2. That topic you referenced uses old V1 code and needs to be updated to V2.

You can find V2 examples in the Java V2 Github Repo located here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager

You can use the Amazon Management console to get to your secrets here :

https://console.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/home?region=us-east-1#!/listSecrets

[image]

To collect a secret, you want to look this code:

```
package com.example.secrets;

//snippet-start:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.SecretsManagerException;
//snippet-end:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 *https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetSecretValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetSecretValue  <secretName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    secretName - the name of the secret (for example, tutorials/MyFirstSecret). \n";

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String secretName = args[0];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        SecretsManagerClient secretsClient = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getValue(secretsClient, secretName);
        secretsClient.close();
    }

    //snippet-start:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.main]
    public static void getValue(SecretsManagerClient secretsClient,String secretName) {

        try {
            GetSecretValueRequest valueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest.builder()
                .secretId(secretName)
                .build();

            GetSecretValueResponse valueResponse = secretsClient.getSecretValue(valueRequest);
            String secret = valueResponse.secretString();
            System.out.println(secret);

        } catch (SecretsManagerException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.main]
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the heads about about the version. I have changed it all for thihs one you recommended!